# react-native > Running android simulator results in "Could not launch" emulator error

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

I'm trying to run a `react-native` android simulator using the `react-native-run-android` library, but I receive the following error:

> Could not launch
>   '/usr/local/bin/../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386'

I have the `emulator` successfully installed, and I can run android from `Android Studio > AVD Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

The library is looking for an `/usr/local/emulator` folder (but it was installed in another directory). First I checked whether the directory existed (it didn't), found where the installation directory actually was, then created a symbolic link to the actual folder location. Finally, check the requested directory exists, then everything worked.

#### i.e.

```sh
$ ls -la /usr/local/emulator
ls: /usr/local/emulator: No such file or directory
$ which emulator
/usr/local/bin/emulator
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/emulator
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user admin  64 13 Aug 09:56 /usr/local/bin/emulator -> /usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/emulator/emulator
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/emulator /usr/local/emulator
Password:
$ ls "/usr/local/bin/../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
/usr/local/bin/../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
```